# how to analyse binomial data with repeated measure in R?

Tags: r

In my experiment I put 10 aphids in the plant and I count the proportion of aphids move/non-moved in the same plant 6, 24 and 48 hours post-infestation. I put 0 for non-moved and 1 for moved. I have a data frame as demonstrated below:

```
data.frame':    1170 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Time     : Factor w/ 3 levels "6","24","48": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Variety  : Factor w/ 3 levels "IA3027","IA3027RA1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ Plants   : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ aphids   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ movement : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ recovered: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to analyze this binomial data with repeated measurements (aphids over time) using R but I don`t know how put my variable that tell R it is a repeated measure. Anybody, can you please help me.

Comment: I suggest to consider Generalized Linear Mixed Models: https://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/courses/ling289/GLMM.pdf

Comment: Or GEE - see the `geepack` package

Comment: Thanks!! My problem is I don`t know how to code my variable to specify for R my repeated measure.